# Ubuntu - Using a utility you can control the 3G traffic?

Tags: iphone-3gs

you need tool to control the time spent 3G traffic, because I have it limited. Simple System Monitor is not very suitable because after the reconnection of data traffic reset spent ...

Answer (score 1):

Found a program NTM - Network Traffic Monitor - this is exactly what you need for a limited internet! You can specify a limit and when it ends it will automatically shut-up! Cool thing!

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/do-you-have-limited-internet-plan-use.html